# User-defind type with built-in type comparison

Tags: python, equality, equivalence

I'm writing a context manager allowing to catch a certain type of exception.

```
class AssertRaises(object):
    def __init__(self, exc_type):
        self.exc_type = exc_type

    def __enter__(self):
        pass

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        if exc_type == self.exc_type:
            raise AssertionError
        return True
```

This manager works fine when built-in exception raises but fails with such usage:

```
class MyTypeError(TypeError):
    pass


try:
    with AssertRaises(TypeError):
        raise MyTypeError()
except Exception as e:
    print(type(e).__name__)
```

In this example the user-defined excepton raises, but this exception is equivalent to TypeError and I want it to be processed by context manager as TypeError.
I checked that `isinstance(MyTypeError(), TypeError) == True' and want

```
__exit__(...)
```

to work in the same way (to consider inheritance). Is there any solution?

Comment: Equality can't test for subclasses no, that's what `issubclass()` is for.

Comment: Note that you should not use `==` to test for classes; `issubclass(Class, Class)` will also return true (a class is deemed a subclass of itself). And don't use `== True` in tests; that is already implied. So instead of `if some_test == True:` use `if some_test:`, and the inverse is `if not some_test:`.

Comment: Thank you for help. I think this is the function i was looking for/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either check the exception itself (`exc_val`) as you've done with `isinstance()`, or use [`issubclass()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#issubclass):

```
def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
    if issubclass(exc_type, self.exc_type):
        raise AssertionError
    return True
```